# wep API with Jquery ,Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a simple web page using nodejs platform , html and jquery . After running my code , I got this error

http://localhost:3000/js/jquery.min.js  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Any suggested solutions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution, get jquery from a CDN.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
```

---

Second solution is to configure **nodejs** to have a *public* folder and there to keep your public files. (if you use `express` packace)

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/js"));
```

And access the file in this way: `<script src="/jquery.min.js"></script>`

---

I recomment you to have **public** folder and there to keep your `javascript` and `css` files.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```

Inside that folder create a structure like this

```
--public
   --css
      -> example.css
   --js
      -> jquery-2.1.3.min.js
```

Add `script` and `link` tags according

```
<link href="/css/example.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
```

And access js/css files like this

```
http://www.example.com/js/jquery.min.js 
http://www.example.com/css/example.css
```

Comment: The first solution :)